# Giving a script Git access to a single Azure Repo

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-repos

I want to poll an Azure Repo for changes with Git. A personal access token from my account would give it too much permissions.

Should I create a new user in Azure AD, add it to Azure Repo with read only and use it in the script? Or is there a better way than creating real users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow your git script to only access one specific Azure Repo. I'm afraid you will need to create a new user as a service account.

After the service account is created and added to your azure devops organization. You can set its access permission to only one repo in the project settings page. See below:

- First deny its access to all the repositories.

**Project settings-**->Click **Git repositories**-->**Search** for the service account-->**Deny Read** permission
[image]

- Then allow the Read permission to that one specific repository.

**Project setting**s-->**Select** the repository you want allow the read permission-->**Search** for the service account-->**Allow Read** permission

The PAT generated from this service account will only have the access to that specific repo.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. A service account is just a normal AD user right?

Comment: Glad to know it works. Yes, A service account is just a normal AD user.