# Direct download URL for universal package in Azure artifacts

Tags: azure-artifacts

we would like to share a URL pointing to an universal package to our company internal customers.
By opening the link the referenced universal package file shall be directly downloaded.

I know that I can use the Azure CLI for achieving the same goal but forcing the people to install and properly configure the Azure CLI only for downloading the package file is not ideal.

Therefore I am interested if there is a way to have a direct download link for a universal package.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, there is NO way to have a direct download link. Please check out below workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is No.

1,If your customers donot have access to your azure devops project.

The most direct workaround i can think of is to create a azure repo and upload the universal package to this repo. Then create a [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) with only `Code-read` scope. Then you can share below commands with your customers. They can download the universal package directly with below git command.

`git clone https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Proj}/_git/{repoName}`

The PAT created above may have the access to your other azure repos. To create a more secure PAT with access to only one repo, you can refer to this thread [Giving a script Git access to a single Azure Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61799938/giving-a-script-git-access-to-a-single-azure-repo/61811527#61811527)

2,If your customers have access to your azure devops project.

They can use their own credential to git clone the universal package azure repo directly.

Pulish the universal package to azure pipeline server as build artifacts as Torsten mentioned is workable too. But it is a little complicated. 
You have to create a pipeline to publish the package and call [Get Artifacts rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get%20artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the download url of the build artifacts. The download url will authenticate Your customers to download the artifacts.(So This is only workable if customers have access to your azure devops project)

Answer (score 2):

You must use the Azure CLI to download the package. Azure DevOps [currently] doesn't support direct HTTP/HTTPS download links or other ways to download the package.

Build/pipeline artifacts can be downloaded, though.