# Pipeline to build debian package using bash script and publish it behind public URL

Tags: linux, .net-core, azure-devops, deb

I'm looking for a way to create a pipeline to first build a .NET Core application, then pack it into a .deb file and finally publish the package file behind a URL to be downloaded from.

This pipeline would be run on pushes to main branch.

Is it possible to accomplish using Azure DevOps pipelines?

I already have:

- pipeline to build the solution and run unit tests for it
- bash script that collects the binaries and packs them into a debian package (.deb) file.

What I need is to run the packaging bash script, then cache/collect the deb file and publish it behind a public/token-accessable URL, e.g. using the Azure artifacts. The package is quite small, around 4 MB.

Comment: probably this is not possible.   :(  I just read "direct download links are not supported" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops#download-a-universal-package

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Universal packages task to publish package (.deb) file to azure artifact.

[image]

For details ,please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=classic).

Comment: I managed to create and publish the artifact using this Unversal Package. How do I get or generate a (public or token-authenticated) URL for the artifact to be downloaded from?

Comment: It seems that it is currently not possible to directly download the package through a URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996528/direct-download-url-for-universal-package-in-azure-artifacts It would be only possible through the Azure REST API with oauth2 authorization flow, or by installing, configuring and using the Azure CLI tool with Azure-Devops extension (this was the option I went with in the end).